# Unrecognized sound on Windows startup lockscreen

Tags: windows, boot, audio

Everytime when I start my computer, it plays a weird sound when I get to this screen:

[image: Windows startup lock-screen]

I haven't even logged-in yet. I still have to enter my password at this point.

This is the sound the thing makes: https://transfer.sh/XEIpj/audio-2017-02-27-10-44-16.ogg (at 00:10).
Alternative link: [http://î.co/sound.ogg](http://%C3%AE.co/sound.ogg)

I have already disabled all startup items.

Does anyone know what this could be? It's been there for a few weeks already.

Comment: The transfer link is broken for me. Could you upload it to some other site?

Comment: @RamonRobben (reply from OP) Here's another site: http://î.co/sound.ogg

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.